# How to avoid a browser security warning about being a deceptive site?

Tags: javascript

I am using below code in my project

```
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  { 
  //x.innerHTML="Latitude:" + position.coords.latitude + 
  //"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  var dataString = 'Latitude='+ position.coords.latitude + '&Longitude='+ position.coords.longitude;
  alert(dataString);
  //AJAX code to submit form.
  //$('#loginprocessing').html('<img src="../images/loading2.gif" alt=" " title="" id="loads" style="margin-left: 0PX;">Loading...');
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "getvalue.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
   $("#demovalues").html(result);
      }
  });
  }
</script>
```

It's working fine in my local but in server I got an error like

> Deceptive site ahead
>
> Attackers on geospeedy.com may trick you into doing something dangerous like installing software or revealing your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, or credit cards). Learn more
>
> Automatically send some system information and page content to Google to help detect dangerous apps and sites. Privacy policy

Comment: If you're fighting an in-built browser warning, I can give you no hope. More info on this message [here](http://botcrawl.com/deceptive-site-ahead/).

Comment: https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fgeospeedy.com%2F You should either stop doing shady things, or cleanup and secure your server.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The warning has absolutely nothing to do with the JavaScript you've posted.

[geospeedy.com has been flagged by Google as a malicious site](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fgeospeedy.com%2F). [Here's more information](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?visit_id=1-636580100079697059-3417529044&p=cpn_safe_browsing&hl=en&rd=1).

Your only course of action is to address the issue that's been flagged and then [request a review](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked/request_review).